# Trigger a command when cding into a directory

Tags: bash

I have recently started writing a lot of applications in Go and there is a requirement for setting up a few environment variables when you want to compile a program.

I am using bash and would like to use a file inside each project directory to set up any environment variables or run any other commands that are needed.

So the idea would be to have a file called `.workspace` that has any commands specific to that particular project inside it. When I cd into a directory having the commands triggered so I don't have to manually set up environment variables or source the `.workspace` file.

I had thought to alias cd to perform the cd and then check for the existence of a `.workspace` file and if it does exist to source the file. It doesn't seem very elegant so I was wondering if there are any other options before going down that route.

I know that rvm - the ruby version manager - does a similar action where it detects a `.rvmrc` file and uses that to set the needed version of ruby for that folder.

Comment: The solution that leaps to mind is the one that you describe...

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/lgoldstien/8453726) then?

Comment: I reckon so :)  Might want to publish that as the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it appears the best way is to alias `cd` to a function that checks for the presence of a `.workspace` file and if it exists, source it.

```
#!/bin/bash

function workspace_cd() {
    cd $@ && [ -f ".workspace" ] && source .workspace
}

alias cd="workspace_cd"
```

So if you source this in your `.profile` it will check for a `.workspace` file and source it. My suggested use for this is to put environment exports in the file:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/lg/Documents/Projects/SomeGoProject
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: So simple but fixed a lot of my code that I was starting to abondon. Thanks!